# Formula for first day of next quarter excel

Tags: excel, date

Could you please help construct a formula to pull the first day of next quarter from today date in Excel? I tried this one

```
=DATE(YEAR(D1),3*INT((MONTH(D1)-1)/3)+1,1)
```

but it actually pulls the first day of the current quarter instead.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You had it very close. This formula works.

```
=DATE(YEAR(D1), ((INT((MONTH(D1)-1)/3)+1)*3)+1, 1)
```

The only problem is in the fourth quarter it goes to 13 and would take some IF statements to get it to round to the next year

Answer (score 1):

Try shifting the math manipulations to a standard worksheet function like the [CEILING function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CEILING-function-0A5CD7C8-0720-4F0A-BD2C-C943E510899F).

```
=DATE(YEAR(D2), CEILING(MONTH(D2), 3),1)
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), CEILING(MONTH(TODAY()), 3),1)
```

I'm not entirely clear on whether you wanted to shift ahead if you are in the first month of the quarter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ceil the month (as number) to significance of 3, and then deduct 2 from the result. So, you will always catch the first month number from any date.

```
=DATE(YEAR(C10),CEILING(MONTH(C10),3)-2,1)
```